# Массив в PHP. Как массив приведенный ниже, будет выглядеть в выводе в в String

Tags: php, массивы

```
['data'=>[
    'courses'=> [
            ['lowDbId'=> 1,'courseName'=>'English for beginners'],
            ['lowDbId'=> 5,'courseName'=>'English for beginners extra'],
        ]
        'country'=>1
    ]
];
```

Доброго, скинули формирование параметров для API, вроде бы на PHP.
Помогите это перевести в тип String, что бы получить сформированную строку параметров.

PS: PHP не знаю и PHP не установлен.

Comment: а что установлено?

Comment: Если добавить недостающую запятую и закрывающую скобку, то получится РНР код. Но что такое "строка параметров" науке неизвестно

Comment: @Ипатьев На счет запятой и скобки - да.  Только получится json, а не php

Comment: @AleksG это РНР, а не джейсон.

Comment: @Ипатьев Вообще-то, да, согласен, только нужно куда-нибудь это присвоить.

Comment: Строка параметров имеет в виду параметры HTTP